# How to hide TabView navigating from tabItem in childview in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am using TabView in swiftui. I want navigate child view from tabview tabItem. When I navigate from taview to childview, it shows tabview in bottom. Here is the image.. that click login goes to Myview page. But in Myview, Tabview is not hiding

[image]

Here is my code..

1. Tabview

   ```
       struct WelcomeView: View {
           var body: some View {

               TabView {
                   HomeView()
                       .tabItem {

                           Image("home_icon")
                           Text("Home")
                       }

                       .tag(0)

                   NotificationView()
                       .tabItem {

                           Image("notification_icon")
                           Text("Notification")
                       }.tag(1)



                   AccountView()
                       .tabItem {

                           Image("account_icon")
                           Text("Account")
                       }.tag(2)

                   SettingView()
                       .tabItem {

                           Image("settings_icon")
                           Text("Setting")
                       }.tag(3)



                }

             }
          }
   ```
2. In SettingView  tabItem:

   ```
        struct SettingView: View {
           @State private var isActive = false

           var body: some View {
               NavigationView {
                   VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                       VStack {
                           Button(action: {
                               isActive = true
                           }) {
                               Text("Login")
                           }
                           NavigationLink("", destination:  MyView(), isActive: $isActive)

                       }
                       }

                   }
               }
           }
   ```
3. MyView:

   ```
      struct MyView: View {
           var body: some View {

               ZStack{
                   Text("Hello My View")
               }.navigationBarHidden(true)
                   .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)


           }
       }
   ```

When I click login Button  in SettingView  tabItem, It goes to  MyView page. But in MyView page tabview is not hide.

How to hide tabview from MyView page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide the tab we can add a `Bool` that will take care of showing the view or not. Then by using `@Binding` we can pass it to the other child views, whatever changes you make down the chain will affect all the views.

[image]

```
struct WelcomeView: View {
    @State var isTabViewShown = true
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            if isTabViewShown {
                HomeView()
                    .tabItem {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                        Text("Home")
                    }
                
                    .tag(0)
                
                NotificationView()
                    .tabItem {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "envelope.open.fill")
                        Text("Notification")
                    }.tag(1)
                
                
                
                AccountView()
                    .tabItem {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                        Text("Account")
                    }.tag(2)
                
                SettingView(isTabViewShown: $isTabViewShown)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                        Text("Setting")
                    }.tag(3)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @Binding var isTabViewShown: Bool
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
                Text("Hello My View")
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(false)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .onAppear {
            isTabViewShown = false
        }
    }
}

struct SettingView: View {
    @State private var isActive = false
    @Binding var isTabViewShown: Bool
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        isActive = true
                    }) {
                        Text("Login")
                    }
                    NavigationLink("", destination:  MyView(isTabViewShown: $isTabViewShown), isActive: $isActive)
                    
                    //Here is a button if you want to show it again
                    Button(action: {
                        isTabViewShown.toggle()
                        //You can also use this is you don't want to use a toggle
//                        isTabViewShown = true
                    }) {
                        Text("Show again")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Home View")
    }
}

struct NotificationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Notification View")
    }
}

struct AccountView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Account View")
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this exact solution on Xcode 13.2 with iOS 15.2. Unfortunately, only the tab items disappear from the view, but the space occupied by the tab view as well as its background remains. I am not sure what workaround there is to resolve that part of the issue ...

Comment: @Andre I'm having trouble reproducing the issue you're having. I copied the code above to a new project, and both the old and new project works in 15.2. Are you sure that you wrapped a `bool` around your tab view contents? Drop a link for your code and maybe I can help.